# How to call sub-tableVIew method from UITabBarViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarViewController *)tabBarController   didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"selected %lu",(unsigned long)tabBarController.selectedIndex);
   if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
  //call refresh() in PlayerTableViewController 
   } else {
    // ...
   }
}
```

Below is `UITabBarViewController`.

In line 4, I have want to call a method called `refresh()` to update data in `PlayerTableViewController`. How can I implement it ?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarViewController *)tabBarController       didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"selected %lu",(unsigned long)tabBarController.selectedIndex);
 if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
 //call refresh() in PlayerTableViewController 
 UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;
 PlayerTableViewController *playerTableVC =(PlayerTableViewController *)  [navController.viewControllers firstObject];
 [playerTableVC.tableView reloadData];



} else {
// ...
}
}
```

Comment: [UINavigationController tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
.
Do I  need to change something in PlayerTableViewController?

Comment: OK, I think your tableView is the root of this NavController. Try now

Comment: If your PlayerVC isn't the root controller of a navigationController in the first index of a tabBar, The code will not work, and I will need where exactly your PlayerVC is in order to help you.

Comment: It worked, Thank you very much. I find it is more difficult to learn OC than Java. Is it true?

Comment: Probably is easier to refresh data in this tableViewController in its own method: viewWillAppear. I don't know why you want update before. I recommend you don't try solve problems in ObjC like you do in Java.

Comment: I saw many websites said  viewWillAppear will not be called, because I use the tabbar. So I choose  refresh data. It seem everything need to be try myself.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not called because in fact the view keep load. But viewWillAppear is called (with a simple NSLog(@"Called"); you can see. And viewWillAppear is called because the view is about to appear. Usually methods in ObjC do what it says.